# Clean duplicate rows on custom conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this problem managing notes. I started with the strategy to always `INSERT` new notes and `SELECT` the last one. Please don't laugh, I must have thought it was a good idea, but right now, the system is not even in all-out production and there's been 300k rows inserted in about a month. In two years, my system will fail. I need to merge duplicate lines. Here is the structure of my `notes` table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ps_notes` (
  `CodeNTE` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CodePRS` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CodeXYZ` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Type` char(3) NOT NULL,
  `Focus` char(3) NOT NULL,
  `Texte` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `Date` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CodeNTE`),
  KEY `CodeXYZ` (`CodeXYZ`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=335068 ;
```

Notes can be related to a person `CodePRS`, are necessarily related to a `Type`, `Focus` and `CodeXYZ`. They have a `Texte` entry and sometime I want to know the `Date`.

`CodeXYZ` is a unique identifier for the entity to which the note is attached. This identifier can come from any table and therefore is not absolutely unique, hence comes the `Type` field. This field specifies from which table the parent row comes. The `focus` field distincts notes that refer to a same `CodeXYZ` and `Type`.

Here some sample lines:

```
+---------+------+-------+-------------+------------+
| CodeXYZ | Type | Focus |    Texte    |    Date    |
+---------+------+-------+-------------+------------+
| 30008   | ctr  | adm   | Whatever    | 2013-05-09 |
| 30008   | ctr  | adm   | Whatever    | 2013-06-10 |
| 30008   | ctr  | adm   | Lorem ipsum | 2013-06-11 |
| 30008   | ctr  | clt   | He's cool   | 0000-00-00 |
| 2546    | ctr  | sup   | Another     | 2013-02-11 |
| 2546    | ctr  | sup   | Another     | 2013-02-11 |
| 2546    | ctr  | sup   | Another     | 2013-02-19 |
+---------+------+-------+-------------+------------+
```

this is the output I'd like to have:

```
+---------+------+-------+-------------+-----------------------------------------+
| CodeXYZ | Type | Focus |    Texte    |                  Date                   |
+---------+------+-------+-------------+-----------------------------------------+
| 30008   | ctr  | adm   | Lorem ipsum | 2013-06-11 (I want the most recent one) |
| 30008   | ctr  | clt   | He's cool   | 0000-00-00                              |
| 2546    | ctr  | sup   | Another     | 2013-02-11                              |
| 2546    | ctr  | sup   | Another     | 2013-02-19                              |
+---------+------+-------+-------------+-----------------------------------------+
```

**Conditions for merging**

1. I want to merge lines that have the same `CodeXYZ`,`Type` and `Focus` when `Focus` is not 'sup'.
2. When `Focus` is 'sup' I want to merge the lines that have the same `CodeXYZ`,`Type`,`Focus` and `Date`
3. Always I want to keep the most recent one

So I ran this query to merge rows in a temporary table:

```
INSERT INTO notes_tmp (CodePRS,CodeXYZ,Type,Focus,Texte,Date)
  SELECT CodePRS,CodeXYZ,Type,Focus,Texte,Date 
  FROM notes 
  GROUP BY CodeXYZ,Type,Focus
```

But that way, all lines will be merged even the last ones.

So I thought of this:

```
INSERT INTO notes_tmp (CodePRS,CodeXYZ,Type,Focus,Texte,Date)
  SELECT CodePRS,CodeXYZ,Type,Focus,Texte,Date 
  FROM notes 
  WHERE Focus<>'sup'
  GROUP BY CodeXYZ,Type,Focus
  ORDER BY Date DESC
UNION
  SELECT CodePRS,CodeXYZ,Type,Focus,Texte,Date 
  FROM notes
  WHERE Focus='sup'
  GROUP BY CodeXYZ,Type,Focus,Date
  ORDER BY Date DESC
```

but UNION is not at the right place, I don't think I can use it in `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` sql syntax

**Is there a way to manage copying those lines over in a single mysql call with multiple sub queries all ending up in the same table acording to separate conditions**

Comment: Which `Texte` do you want?

Comment: The most recent one if there are dates, if not any one

Comment: I thought date was NOT NULL !?!?

Comment: it sometimes contains '0000-00-00' sorry

Comment: @Félix Gagnon-Grenier i think i got what you need this time. check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So with part of @Volkan answer, I could come up with this somehow strangely working sql to get the correct note out of my GROUP_CONCAT()

The case will get the last entry of the group concat. I used another separator (,,,) because commas do happen often in text. three in a row a little bit less.

```
INSERT INTO notes_temp
SELECT CodeXYZ,Type, Focus,Texte,Date 
FROM notes WHERE Focus = 'sup'
GROUP BY CodeXYZ,Type, Focus,Date;

INSERT INTO notes_temp
SELECT 
CodeXYZ,
Type, 
Focus,
CASE
  WHEN COUNT(Texte) > 1
    THEN SUBSTR(GROUP_CONCAT(Texte SEPARATOR ",,,"),((LENGTH(GROUP_CONCAT(Texte SEPARATOR ",,,"))+2) - INSTR(REVERSE(GROUP_CONCAT(Texte SEPARATOR ",,,")),",,,")))
  ELSE
    Texte
  END
AS Texte,
MAX(Date)
FROM notes WHERE Focus <> 'sup'
GROUP BY CodeXYZ,Type, Focus;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `group_concat` to merge text field and make other columns unique with `group by`. try this:

```
INSERT INTO notes_temp
SELECT CodeXYZ,Type, Focus,GROUP_CONCAT(Texte),Date 
FROM notes WHERE Focus = 'sup'
GROUP BY CodeXYZ,Type, Focus,Date;

INSERT INTO notes_temp
SELECT CodeXYZ,Type, Focus,GROUP_CONCAT(Texte),MAX(Date)
FROM notes WHERE Focus <> 'sup'
GROUP BY CodeXYZ,Type, Focus;
```

check [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9a33a/1)

Comment: while this is certainly useful, the three first (CodeXYZ=30008,Type='ctr',Focus='adm') line end up not merged at all in your fiddle while I want them to be merged. please see the sample and exemple of desired result in my question.

Comment: well you can't say for this particular row i want to merge those with same date and for this particular row i don't want to merge those with the same date. or you can say that, but you can't possibly convert that into machine language because you don't have custom conditions, you have unpredictable conditions, which not only machines, but humans also can't understand

Comment: Right, I've clarified the conditions, if you care please see the question.

Comment: Yes, this is much more like it. The only problem is that all the `Texte` values are there, and removing the `GROUP_CONCAT` doesn't keep the last note which is the one I need, but I'll find a way to manage that.

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot, I could get exactly what I want by adding some things to the group_concat. thanks for the thumbs up. here's the new fiddle if you like http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fce7a/1